# Tornado 5.1.1 not installing with pip

Tags: python

I'm new to all of this, and I need to use Jupyter notebook for one of my school assignments. However, I got some kernel couldn't start issue when I used it.After searching up online, I found that I should downgrade tornado to 5.1.1. So I tried doing that, but it always give me the same error. Can someone please help me figure out what the issue is.

```
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [20 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-j21_r432\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 325, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-j21_r432\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 295, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-j21_r432\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 480, in run_setup
          super().run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "C:\Users\Max\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-j21_r432\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 311, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 146, in <module>
      ImportError: Tornado requires an up-to-date SSL module. This means Python 2.7.9+ or 3.4+ (although some distributions have backported the necessary changes to older versions).
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

Like I said, I'm pretty clueless, so the only thing I really tried was completely uninstalling tornado and then reinstalling at 5.1.1, but I just get the same error.

Comment: "Tornado requires an up-to-date SSL module": since Tornado is being installed from source, you lack the necessary libraries. Probably the combination of your Python version, OS and Tornado version doesn't have a precompiled Tornado package, and you have to build from source.

Comment: A quick glance at the Tornado PyPI page shows only pre-compiled builds (wheels) for Python 3.8. Presumably, later Python versions will also work, but I'm not sure if pip will use the 3.8 wheels for that. Tornado version 5.1.1, however, only supports up to Python 3.7; you'll want to try and use a more recent Tornado version (current version is 6.4).

Comment: "After searching up online, I found that I should downgrade tornado to 5.1.1.": where did you find that? Because that advice might be too old to work with Python 3.12. And what version of Jupyter are using? And what version is your OS?

Comment: "I got some kernel couldn't start issue when I used it:": this is your actual issue. You looked for a solution, found one, that didn't work, but now you've focused on that troubleshooting that solution. Perhaps you should ask a new question, with the original issue, mention what you have tried (with links to relevant solutions tried). That may be better than trying to downgrade Tornado.

Answer (score 0):

tornado 5.1.1 supports "Python 2.7 and Python 3.4 - 3.7". You are using Python 3.12.

If you want to use this older release of tornado, you may have to downgrade your python version to 3.7 and then `pip install tornado==5.1.1`. See https://pypi.org/project/tornado/5.1.1/#data

Comment: Given the original problem of the OP (trying to get Jupyter to run), downgrading all the way to Python 3.7 and running Tornado 5.1.1 is probably not the proper solution to their problem.